# Installing python pacakages in Mac

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, python-dedupe

I am a new user to python and I am trying to install a package in Visual Code using anaconda. I type in the following code

`pip install pandas-dedupe`

But I receive this error

```
/Users/nathang./anaconda3/bin/python /Users/nathang./Desktop/python/example.py
  File "/Users/nathang./Desktop/python/example.py", line 1
    pip install pandas-dedupe
        ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
(base) nathang.@MacBook-Pro python %
```

Any help would be appreciated as I have been trying to figure this out for a few hours.

Comment: Did you type the `pip install pandas-dedupe` inside `example.py`? That's not going to work.... type it into a terminal for example.

Comment: You're trying to execute `pip install pandas-dedupe` as python code.  But it isn't python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` is meant to be used from the terminal, you are typing it into a script (`example.py`).

From within VSCode press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on Windows) which will open a panel on the bottom of the window. Press the `Terminal` tab and type your command `pip install pandas-dedupe` in the terminal which opens.